# How to open a CLI program in python and enter a command(Mac OSX)?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, command-line-interface

I have a Mac program with a command line interface that I am trying to automate from Python. So far I have:

```
os.system("cd /Applications/program/MyApp.app/Contents/bin/; ./MyApp -prompt;")
```

Which runs the CLI. Now I want to enter a command into the command line from Python. Is there a way to pass this in as an argument to the first command?

Example:

```
os.system("cd /Applications/program/MyApp.app/Contents/bin/; ./MyApp -prompt; and then run MySpecialCommand in CLI")
```

I'm not commited to a specific approach, I just need to be able to enter the command into the CLI from a python script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Agreed with duplicate. The first (accepted) answer even explains why to use `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [sys.argv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv):

```
import os
import sys

my_string = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])

template_cmd = "cd /Applications/program/MyApp.app/Contents/bin/; ./MyApp -prompt; {additional_arg}"

os.system(template_cmd.format(additional_arg=my_string))
```

This would be run as follows:

```
python my_script.py ls -l
```

Where `ls -l` would be your entered command.

Comment: here, argparse is probably overkill (although it's a very useful module). The OP is only expecting one argument, with no need to transform or inspect them.

Comment: How would you write this If there were only ever going to be one command and it would always be the same?

Comment: Why would you have it in the CLI if it were always the same?

Comment: I want python to enter it into the programs command line. I don't want to enter it from the command line myself.